# Split text file Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, split

I am working on text files like this:

> **Chapter 01**
>
> Lorem ipsum
>
> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
>
> **Chapter 02**
>
> consectetur adipiscing
>
> sed do eiusmod tempor
>
> **Chapter 03**
>
> et dolore magna aliqua.

with delimiters like "chapter", "Chapter", "CHAPTER", etc... and 1 or 2 digits ("Chapter 1" or "Chapter 01").

I managed to open and read the file in Python, with `.open()` and `.read()`

```
mytext = myfile.read()
```

Now I need to split my string, in order to get text for "Chapter XX".

For Chapter 02, that would be :

> consectetur adipiscing
>
> sed do eiusmod tempor

I'm new to Python, I read about regex, match, map, or split, but... well...

(I'm writing a Gimp Python-fu plugin, so I use Python version bundled in Gimp, which is 2.7.15).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions like so:

```
import re

split_text = re.split("Chapter [0-9]+\n",  # splits on "Chapter " + numbers + newline
                      mytext, 
                      flags=re.IGNORECASE) # splits on "CHAPTER"/"chapter"/"Chapter" etc
```

```py
>>> split_text
['', '\nLorem ipsum\n\ndolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt\n\n', '\nconsectetur adipiscing\n\nsed do eiusmod tempor\n\n', '\net dolore magna aliqua.']
```

You can now choose the text from each chapter by the index of `split_text` e.g.:

```
print(split_text[2])

>>> 
consectetur adipiscing

sed do eiusmod tempor
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this bellow

```
chapter = [""]
for i in range(1,4):

  nb1=text.find("Chapter "+ "%02d" % (i,))
  nb2=text.find("Chapter "+ "%02d" % (i+1,))

  chapter.append(text[nb1:nb2])

for i in range(1,4):
    print(chapter[i])
```

or with regular expressions :

```
import re

chapter = re.split("Chapter [0-4]+\n", text)

for i in range(1,4):
    print(chapter[i])
```

Comment: `with delimiters like chapter, Chapter, CHAPTER, etc... and 1 or 2 digits (Chapter 1 or Chapter 01)` This doesn't account for the variability in case in 'Chapter', or for chapter numbers out of the example's scope, or for numbers less than 10 without leading 0's (in the first code block, the regex expression  does capture this last case).

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re

# removing void strings.
splitted_str = list(filter(lambda x: x != '', re.split("Chapter [0-9]+", my_text)))
print(splitted_str)
```